# MS Graph can't open a new browser activity when Chrome is disabled/deleted of device

Tags: android, xamarin, microsoft-graph-api

I have developed a xamarin form app that it uses MS Graph in order to user sign in. I have used samples of GitHub that open a new browser activity where user sign in and then the app goes to home activity. It works correctly. But some users have blocked or deleted Chrome app in order to use MS Edge as default browser, and then when app tries to start the browser activity, it launches an error because it can’t find chrome activity.  I have asked on MS Graph GitHub (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/242 ) but they and I are thinking that it isn’t problem of SDK but I don’t know how I could fix it. How should I fix it in order to work with any installed browser?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is done by design. The Microsoft Identity Client library uses Custom Chrome tabs and does not have any fallback strategy to run using a WebView.

You are probably encountering this exception thrown when it doesn't find Chrome installed: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Identity.Client/Platforms/Android/AuthenticationActivity.cs#L131

```
string chromePackageWithCustomTabSupport = GetChromePackageWithCustomTabSupport(ApplicationContext);

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(chromePackageWithCustomTabSupport))
{
    string chromePackage = GetChromePackage();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(chromePackage))
    {
        throw new MsalClientException(MsalClientException.ChromeNotInstalledError,
            "Chrome is not installed on the device, cannot proceed with authentication");
    }
```

Comment: I don't receive this error, app crashs and it is closed automatically. The error is this: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=https://login.microsoftonline.com/... pkg=com.android.chrome }
android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult()` then there aren't solution while.. 
I will notify the problem in order to may be future improvement of SDK. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

@Cheesebaron is correct, this is by design. Currently, Xamarin Android in MSAL can only launch chrome or chrome custom tabs. If the device doesn't have them, it will cause an exception, as you noted above.

@cansado2930 This part of the error message `pkg=com.android.chrome` means Chrome is not installed on the device.

Embedded webview support in MSAL will be an option in near future.

Here's a link to the [issue in the MSAL repo](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/547).

Comment: Thank Jenny, I saw it a few days ago, But I opened the issue on february on the same repo: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/534